# How do you show and hide widgets in PyQt5?

Tags: python, attributes, pyqt5

I'm trying to make an introduction for my game organization, but I've been roadblocked at trying to hide label_2 here. I've been searching on StackOverflow and other code help websites, but none of the solutions presented to me work.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import time

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(470, 384)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.logo = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.logo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 30, 100, 100))
        self.logo.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
        self.logo.setText("")
        self.logo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Alpha_Software_logo.png"))
        self.logo.setObjectName("logo")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 140, 331, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(36)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 250, 201, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 470, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Alpha Software"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Powering minds since 2019"))
        # Line needed to hide label_2
        time.sleep(3)
        # Line needed to show label_2



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.hide` to hide and `.show` to show with a `QTimer` (`time.sleep` doesn't work in PyQt):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(470, 384)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.logo = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.logo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 30, 100, 100))
        self.logo.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
        self.logo.setText("")
        self.logo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Alpha_Software_logo.png"))
        self.logo.setObjectName("logo")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 140, 331, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(36)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 250, 201, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 470, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Alpha Software"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Powering minds since 2019"))
        self.label_2.hide()
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(3000, lambda: self.label_2.show())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```